# Can a Language accept Infinite numbers

Tags: regular-language, turing-machines, dfa, computation-theory

I have a question whether a language can accept infinite numbers

I have to reduce Lempty to Linf

```
where Lempty ={e|L(Pe) is null}
Linf={e|L(Pe) is infinite}
```

so can i define a program P like this

```
"
input n
Run Pe on 1...n for n steps
if Pe accept any number then enter an infinite loop and start accepting infinite number
if pe does not accept any number then accept 1"
```

Now if i can define program P like above then asking the question whether Language accepted by P belong to Linf will tell me whether Language accepted by Pe is null or not.

Any advice or suggestions is always welcome

Comment: Probably better-suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thanks,will post there too

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit ill-defined, but here's an approximation:
In standard computational theory, languages cannot contain infinite strings. Infinite number is unclear. If you mean a number **requiring** infinite digits to precisely represent, no. Standard automata cannot recognize infinite length strings (how could it ever terminate?). However, many numbers that **appear to require** infinite digits (consider one-third as .3333333...) do not require infinite characters to represent otherwise, making them candidates for any language.

Hope that helps, depending on what exactly you're asking.